# Criar um option selected jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

Já vi varias postagens sobre isso, mas nenhuma conseguiu me ajudar definitivamente.

Estou querendo colocar um option selected de forma dinâmica(dados do db).

```
obj.nome = [vitor,joao,carlos]

  dep_option += '<option name ='+obj.nome+'>'+obj.nome+'</option>';
  dep_select = '<select name="select_'+obj.nome+'">'+dep_option+'</select>';
  $('body').html(dep_select).show();
```

Desse modo como eu coloco o option joao como selected.

Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Em vez de vc usar `name` no `option`, deveria usar `value`, que seria o valor referente ao  respectivo `option`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não ficou muito claro qual seria a forma dinâmica, mas basta usar `$("select").val("joao")`, segue um código funcional usando seu exemplo:

```js
var button = $("button")

button.on("click", function() {

  var obj = {};
  obj.nome = ["vitor", "joao", "carlos"];

  var dep_option = "";
  $.each(obj.nome, function(i) {
    dep_option += '<option name=' + obj.nome[i] + '>' + obj.nome[i] + '</option>';
  });

  var dep_select = '<select id="selecionar" name="select_' + obj.nome + '">' + dep_option + '</select>';
  dep_option += dep_option;

  $('body').html(dep_select).show();
  $('#selecionar').val('joao');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button>Montar Select!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Não foi bem isso, mas ajudou a reformular minha ideia.
Obrigado.